# INotifyPropertyChanged Base class

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged

If I have a base class that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
public class ResourceWrapperBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Does firing the propertychanged event in the base class, like this:

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null))
```

Also update all the bindings on properties in classes that inherit from this base class?

```
public class ResourceWrapper : ResourceWrapperBase
```

So in other words, I want to update all bindings to properties in ResourceWrapper when the propertychanged event in ResourceWrapperBase is fired.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually firing PropertyChanged event with PropertyChangedEventArgs(null) causes all bindings to be updated.

Comment: That's what I thought, but it's not updating the bindings in the subclasses.

Comment: Silly me, I forgot to add <SupportedCultures> in the csproj file